# Error with importing module in python

Tags: python, macos

Please have you a trail for this problem below, on the same computer (mac OS 10.6.8) :

```
toto$ python
Python 2.7.9 (v2.7.9:648dcafa7e5f, Dec 10 2014, 10:10:46) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 109, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 32, in pylab_setup
    globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_macosx.py", line 24, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends import _macosx
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/_macosx.so, 2): Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
  Expected in: /opt/local/lib/libjpeg.9.dylib
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
```

For the user toto.
But for one other user, titi, i obeserved no problem :

```
titi$ python
Python 2.7.9 (v2.7.9:648dcafa7e5f, Dec 10 2014, 10:10:46) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>>
```

Any suggestions will be very appreciated !!!!

Comment: My guess would be that you are picking-up an older version of matplotlib.  You probably installed 2..7.9 yourself, so check PYTHONPATH environment variable.

Comment: is /opt/local/ and everything under it readable by the toto user? Homebrew normally installs things *as* a particular user, if you installed as titi, toto might not be able to read some files.

Comment: Python looks for the module in [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path). Try `>>> import sys; print sys.path`, and see whether there's a difference between `titi` and `toto`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. @cdarke and Peter:  The sys.path is exactly the same for the users titi and toto.

Comment: @SingleN, /opt/local and everything under is -rwxr-xr-x  root admin, Then yes it is readable. If I remember well I installed packages with pip2.7. As every times it will be just a little dust that blocks the gear and I do not yet find the dust, arghhh !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just find the dust :-(((
User toto had, for unknown reason, this ~/.bash_profile file:

```
export PATH=~/bin:/opt/local/bin:${PATH}
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib:${DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH}


# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

I changed this file by:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then 
    source ~/.bashrc 
fi
```

In .bashrc I leave only alias and commands for prompt.

All is working now :-)))
thanks for your suggestions, that helps for find the trail !

Comment: Does that mean `sys.path` wasn't exactly the same for users `titi` and `toto`?

Comment: Yes exactly the same. Thanks for your suggestion.